# How to determine if Box2D fixture or shape is solid?

Tags: c#, c++, box2d, farseer

I think it is very simple to do but somehow I cannot find the way to do it. I want to draw selected fixtures and I don't really know if they should be filled or not - there is nothing like `Fixture.IsSolid` or `Shape.IsSolid`.

I actually do it in Farseer, but it is only Box2D for C# actually.

**EDIT:** I've checked Farseer examples for this and it seems they just assume all are solids. They certainly do not have to be..

Comment: If your fixture is filled with the background color, is it solid or empty?  What fill color would represent solid?  Is a fixture filled with a pattern considered solid?

Comment: I don't know much about Farseer, but in Box2D polygons and circle shapes will always be solid, while chain and edge shapes are not solid.

Comment: @iforce2d Thank you for this information. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Farseer, but in Box2D polygons and circle shapes will always be solid, while chain and edge shapes are not solid.